# RecyclerView with Kotlin not laying out cells vertically

Tags: listview, android-recyclerview, kotlin

My list is only showing a single row of data, even though the expected 4 rows pass through the `ViewHolder`.

The `RecyclerView`, `RecyclerView.Adapter`, and `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` are all working as I expect AFAICT. I see the correct 4 rows of data passing through the bind function. However, I only see one row in the list. It is as if the `LinearLayoutManager` isn't correctly laying out the cells in a vertical orientation. I'm not sure what has been missed.

```
class SongListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mediaProvider:MediaProvider

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mediaProvider = MediaLibraryTestSongProvider()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        //TODO: how to inflate fragment using Kotlin extension?
        val songListView            = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song_list, container, false)
        val songListRecyclerView    = songListView.songListRecyclerView

        songListRecyclerView.layoutManager  = LinearLayoutManager( activity )
        songListRecyclerView.adapter        = SongListCellAdapter(mediaProvider.getSongs() )

        return songListView
    }

    private inner class SongListCellAdapter(val songList:List<Song>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SongListCellHolder>()
    {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) : SongListCellHolder {
            val inflater        = LayoutInflater.from( activity )
            val songCellView    = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_song_list,parent,false)
            val holder          = SongListCellHolder( songCellView )

            return holder
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SongListCellHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bind(songList[position])
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return songList.size
        }
    }

    private inner class SongListCellHolder(itemView:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        fun bind( song:Song ) = with(itemView) {
            songTitle.text  = song.title
            songArtist.text = song.artist
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the syntax for the Kotlin Extensions. It replaces the normal findViewById() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be simple (once you know the answer). My layout for the cell, `cell_song_list` had `layout_height="match_content"` which resulted in each cell being the size of the screen. The others were there, but off screen, and on the simulator I didn't scroll to notice.

For the record, here is my corrected layout for the cell, with the top level `LinearLayout` using `layout_height="wrap_content"`, so the cells are the correct size.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        tools:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songArtist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is quite common mistake.